# Scaling singletons

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns, anti-patterns

After having some difficult hours mulling over some architecture issues for my server-based application, I feel I am going to have to use singletons to accomplish my goal. Purely for the following reasons (justifying my smell):

- I don't need to pass expensive objects deep into a call stack
- I can perform functions on singleton management objects within any context. (A lot of the code already exists and therefore I am unwilling to rewrite extensive chunks of otherwise working code)

Apart from that, Singletons suggest another problem. My server-based application is essentially a DLL with a class that can invoke multiple instances of servers. The server instance class contains the singleton management objects. Ordinarily, this would be managed by a Windows Service, so server:machine ratio will be 1:1.

So you could view it as (where -> is 1:1, => is 1:many):

MACHINE -> ServiceHost (Windows service?) -> Server instance -> Singleton management objects

However, we would like to allow for an SaaS model, which would require a service host (be it a Windows Service or Win32 application) to be able to fire up multiple servers as required by the business. Therefore, a physical machine could run a single server host, which would run multiple server instances.

Which would be (where -> is 1:1, => is 1:many):

MACHINE -> ServiceHost (Windows service?) **=>** Server instance -> *Singleton management objects*

The problem is that these singletons would be shared across servers. Which cannot happen. The singletons must be 1:1 with the server instance.

Assuming I cannot move away from these singletons, is it possible for me to separate these server instances from each other by invoking the service instance class as a separate process/memory space?

I can only imagine that I would need to fire up multiple EXEs (anduse WCF to manage), one for each server instance. This would obviously not be very good.

Comment: Thinking about it, could I use Reflection somehow?

Comment: How is the server instance going to access the management objects?

Comment: What are you doing? Your problem doesn't seem to be described in the above; and I have no concept of what "Scaling Singletons" means ... (How do you have more than 1 ...; that seems counter-intuitive, to say the least :P)

Comment: @Lazarus: The server instance (say IServerInstance) has properties that it initialised on Start(). They're just static properties specific to that service instance.

Comment: @silky: I'm basically trying to take an application that was a Web app to be a Win32 service, but adding the possibility of scaling up instances of servers to offer a potential SaaS business case. So if you have IServerInstance with its own static properties, I need to be able to fire up a second instance, independent of the first - but preferably without an intermediate layer - eg. separate process and therefore WCF

Comment: Program.X: Ah-ha. I see. Seems like you want to launch it in a new AppDomain, like Benjamin suggests below. But I don't think you mean "Win32" service (i.e. not even .net). I'd say it's worthwhile considering if you can just completely remove the singleton, but that may not be practical. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about different AppDomains for different "Instances"?

Comment: Looking into this, this looks very promising. It looks as if I can even communicate between the host and the AppDomains (containing single server instances). Thanks.