# Client hangs when sending multiple messages to wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

I am trying to send multiple messages to WCF service. It works fine if message count is small, but if I send a lot of messages (let's say 50), then sending application hangs. It eventually gets unable to write to pipe exception.

Here is the code for sending messages

```
for (var i=0; i< 50; i++)
    WcfChannel.SomeMethod(SomeParameter);
```

And here is the some server configuration code

```
_host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TService));
var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding
{
    SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(4),
    ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(4),
    MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
    MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
};
_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TInterface), binding, Address);
```

Server implementation

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class WcfService
{ ... }
```

And here is the exception message which I get after timeout

> There was an error writing to the pipe: The pipe is being closed. (232, 0xe8).

So what is the problem here? Is there problem with server settings?

**Update 1:**

If I send 50 messages, then I get exception. After catching exception I sent 50 more messages. It worked fine. And after that I sent 100 messages. It also worked fine. Why this happens for the first time only?,

Comment: Please try:  ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple in the ServiceBehaviour attribute

Comment: See WCF service behavior: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/443576/Implementing-WCF-Service-Behaviors

Comment: Here is an update. I sent 50 messages and I received an exception, after that I send 50 more messages, they work fine. After that I sent 100 more messages, it also worked fine. Why it doesn't work for the first time?

Comment: I am not sure that I can change service concurrency mode or not. Is there any solution for single mode?,

Comment: I changed ConcurrencyMode to Multiple, but I am still getting exception,

Comment: Why do you need the service to be a singleton?

Comment: Service needs to store some data. It cannot be changed. Else we need to initializa data again and again which will effect performance,

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027263/scaling-singletons